# How to Escape a While Controller after 10 Minutes

Tags: jmeter, jexl

I've created a While Controller in Apache JMeter that I want to run for 10 minutes or until an exit condition is met. However the following function doesn't work.

`${__jexl3(
    ("${start}" + 600000) > "${__time()}" || "${exit}"
)}`

I'm new to JMeter. I may be misunderstanding how the JEXL evaluation works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove quotation marks around the variables, otherwise [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) would be comparing [Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) instead of [Longs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html)

```
${__jexl3(${start} + 600000 > ${__time(,)},)}
```

You can use i.e. [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide) in order to evaluate various parts of the expression and the whole expression. The results can be visualized via [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

[image]